# Im getting an error in my root view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know it's a very common error .. I'm using storyboard and I'm getting this error, here's my [AppDelegate.m screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdLe3.jpg)

keep in mind that I'm beginner and the reason of that maybe so stupid :)
Thanks in advance!

(it's not a bug but I'm just getting a black screen on the simulator)

Comment: yes no issues .. but I'm just getting a black screen and this error in the console :(

Comment: the screenshot shows no error, edit your question to post information in it rather than linking outside of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

instead of:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer .. but could you please explain more where do I use it ? :)

Comment: Thank you again for your reply .. but that didn't solve my problem :( I'm still getting a black screen .. any other fixes ?

Comment: add this code: viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: before: window.rootViewController = viewController;

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice your second comment .. I have added it before window.rootViewController = viewController; .. but I still get the black screen :'(

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you don't create a `UIWindow` yourself when you use storyboard. When using storyboard, the main `UIWindow` is created for you. Since you created your own `UIWindow`, it's just overlapping and covering up the existing `UIWindow`. Set the `rootViewController` in `.storyboard` by pointing that arrow to it.

By the way, did you create a single view application or an empty application?

Comment: Thank you for reply .. it's a Single View application .. and I haven't created any UIWindow there is just one viewController with UIScrollView in my storyboard .. and keep in mind that I'm beginner so please explain more about your answer :)

Comment: When you created the single view application, did you check storyboard? Or you added storyboard after you created your single view application?

Comment: Actually it's the storyboard which is automatically made with the project (I haven't added it manually) .. by the way I have linked all outlets successfully but all codes in this project was used in another project but with a xib not a storyboard .. can this be related to the error ?

Comment: Thank you @yeesterbunny .. but are you sure 100% ?? .. and can this be fixed ?

Comment: Of course this can be fixed. You just need to play around with it.

Comment: hmmmm ... To be honest I'm too beginner to do this myself .. could  you explain or give me your e-mail to discuss .. I will pay for you if you want BUT I JUST NEED TO GET THIS FIXED ! or you could give easy tutorial for how to make UIScrollView with pages (image gallery) ?